# Blue Highlight around Custom NSButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I want to make a custom NSButton with a solid color for its background but there is this blue highlight around the button that I can't figure out how to get rid of. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

[image: image of button]

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the code for the button:

@implementation ZDButton

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.title = @"";
        self.isSelected = false;
        [self setBordered:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0
                               green:arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0
                                blue:arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0
                               alpha:1.0] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    NSDictionary *att = nil;
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style =
    [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [style setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];
    att = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
           style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
           [NSColor whiteColor],
           NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    int width = [self.title sizeWithAttributes:att].width;
    int height = [self.title sizeWithAttributes:att].height;
    int x = (dirtyRect.size.width - width) / 2;
    int y = (dirtyRect.size.height - height) / 2;

    NSRect centeredText = NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(x, y, width, height));
    [self.title drawInRect:centeredText withAttributes:att];

}

@end
```

Comment: If you don't show your code we can't figure it out either.

Comment: What we can see looks like a TableView cell view. That means you need to learn about how view based tables work. Rows are normally highlighted by the containing table row view. Table cell views are normally clear containers of other widgets. Selected rows are highlighted by the drawing of table row views

Comment: This might help: `[self setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];`

Comment: What class does it inherit from and what is the view hierarchy it is inside of?

Comment: @uchuugaka: NSButton, Gerd K: Doesn't get rid of it :(

Comment: But what is the button inside of?